Why does energy stored in a capacitor increase with the square of voltage?
The energy stored in a capacitor is \$\frac{1}{2}C\times{}V^2\$. Yet a potential difference is itself a measure of the energy stored per unit of charge. (with units Joule per Coulomb). Shouldn't the voltage across a capacitor directly relate, then, to the amount of energy it stores, instead of the square root of it?

Because the surface area of a right-angled triangle grows quadratically with the length of its leg ;-).

More voltage means more charge, and also more energy per charge.

Don't let that to mislead you into thinking that a low-cost ceramic SMD capacitor will behave this way. As a matter of fact, the higher the voltage, the lower their capacitance. The square energy relation is true for a classic plate capacitor, but not the low-cost ones in our everyday gadgets.

Let me make an analogy of your question using another relationship between electrical quantities, For example, from:
"The power dissipated varies with the square of the current", when writing:
$$P= \text{R}I^2 \qquad [1]$$
But wait! Wouldn't it actually be:
"The power dissipated is directly proportional to the current", when writing:
$$P=\text{V}I \qquad [2]$$
The explanation lies in the fact that the above statements are incomplete:
\$[1]\$ could be: "For a constant load, the power dissipated varies with the square of the current". In this case, the voltage must change.
\$[2]\$ could be: "For a constant voltage, the power dissipated varies proportionally with the current". In this case, the load must change.
So, regarding your question:
"The energy stored in the capacitor varies with the square of the voltage",
when writing:
$$ E=\frac{1}{2}\text{C}V^2 \qquad [3] $$
where, a more complete interpretation could be:
"For a constant capacitance, the energy stored varies with the square of the voltage". In this case, the charge must change.
or
"The energy stored in the capacitor is directly proportional to its voltage", when writing:
$$ E=\frac{1}{2}\text{Q}V \qquad [4]$$
where, a  more complete interpretation could be:
"For a constant charge, the energy stored in the capacitor is directly proportional to the voltage". In this case, the capacitance must change.

Note: In each of the expressions above, I have kept a factor not written in italics, with the aim of highlighting a constant, relevant only to the context presented in the answer. This is not always the case.

No, because each additional unit of charge added to the capacitor makes it harder to add the next unit of charge; the capacitor's voltage rises, so the external voltage must rise to "push" the additional charge onto the plate. The work required to add the additional charge, dW, is equal to \$\frac{q}{C}dq\$. Integrating this over the total amount of charge stored gives \$\frac{1}{2}CV^2\$.

This effect is apparent in a Van de Graaff generator. When the charged sphere rises to a high voltage, the motor that turns the charging belt slows down.

Stored energy is area under the charge x voltage plot, which is a triangle.  If that much charge was added or discharged at constant voltage, energy would be CV^2, area under a rectangle with sides V and CV.  But it's not, it's a triangle; that's where the factor of 1/2 comes in.  (Integral calculus is a more general way of getting areas under curves, but for simple shapes we can sometimes just use geometric arguments, and it can sometimes shed some light on the physical meaning of what we're calculating.)

The definition of capacitance is that the voltage difference between the plates is \$V_{_\text{C}}=\frac{q}{C}\$ or that \$C=\frac{q}{V_{_\text{C}}}\$ and \$q=C\cdot V_{_\text{C}}\$.
The work done to add charge \$\text{d}q\$ is \$\text{d}W=V_{_\text{C}}\:\text{d}q \$ (verify for yourself that the dimensional units work out, correctly.)
As \$\text{d} q=C\: \text{d}V_{_\text{C}}\$, find \$\text{d}W=V_{_\text{C}}\cdot C\: \text{d}V_{_\text{C}}\$.
Now just integrate:
$$\begin{align*}
W&=\int \text{d}W=\int_{_0}^{V}V_{_\text{C}}\cdot C\: \text{d}
V_{_\text{C}}
\\\\
&=C\int_{_0}^{V}V_{_\text{C}}\: \text{d}V_{_\text{C}}
\\\\
&=\frac12 C\,V^{^2}
\end{align*}$$
As long as the addition of charge remains with the same sign, work to add that charge increases as the voltage difference across the capacitor continually increases. This should make qualitative sense in your gut, too.

Consider a discharged capacitor fed from a constant current source. At activation, the voltage across the capacitor is zero and, despite the constant current, there can be no energy or power into the capacitor because the voltage is at zero volts.
A little later, the voltage has risen and the power into the capacitor is not zero any more. A little later, the voltage has risen a bit more and, the power must rise proportional to the voltage rise. After all power = voltage × current and, current is constant.
So, in charging the capacitor, the power rises proportional to the voltage and, if we wanted to know the energy accumulated in the capacitor, we would integrate power with respect to time and see that energy transferred is proportional to voltage squared.
